# Grazing Adaptations in Many-Mouthed Animals

Tags: evolution, food

In a world I am designing, most animals have many mouths placed directly in their side. These mouths have two jaws like in sharks, and also have a small pair of palps for manipulating food, which act like tongues. They also have legs (in a single line), a mobile head, and a pair of arms/tails in the back for balance

While this system would work well for browsers, I don't see how they would adapt to grazing on low-growing grass-like plants. It also wouldn't make much sense for these grass-likes to be without a predator

The grazers would need to be significantly larger than the grass they eat, similar to real grazers

What are some adaptations that could be common amongst these grazers for gathering these low-growing plants

Specifically, I'd like the answers to provide adaptations that are realistic, and stay close to the original body-plan, rather than grossly increasing certain parts or forming new structures

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Has my edit helped?

Comment: Yes, quite a bit. Like a combination of a caterpillar and a monorail ;)

Comment: Some ideas, no time for an answer now.. mouths on the side.. to graze effectively you'd move sidewards as well. And concerning physiology: when you have a grazer, you'd need some room in each mouth for the molars. One feature of ruminants is their continuously growing teeth. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruminant

Comment: I can't help but wonder why evolution would put mouths on both (or more) sides.  In my head, I see an animal adapted to clear absolutely every bit of edible material in its path, leaving nothing behind.  But, regardless of which direction it moves, how many sides it has, and how many of those sides have mouths, there will always be only (at most) 50% of the sides that are encountering food while the animal moves.  the other 50% encounter only the bare ground picked clean by the first set.  So why have the second set?  At best, only half of them will be useful at any given feeding time.

Comment: @Harthag The first mouths won't get all of the food, so the extra pairs will get the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grass is generally on the ground, which makes it harder to reach with your mouth when you're standing up, unless you have the kind of neck/body that allows you to put your mouth close to the ground.
But there is at least one exception, which is the elephant. It has the ability to pick stuff up from the ground and put it in it's mouth.

If I'm visualizing these creatures correctly, they don't have necks at all, so instead use their extra long and flexible palps like an elephant uses it's trunk to harvest grass from the ground, and move it to it's mouth.

Answer (score 2):

**No Stomach.**

Unlike life on Earth, these animals do digestion and mastication in a single orifice. They continuously chew their food while soaking it in enzymes until the nutrients are ready to be absorbed into the bloodstream through the back wall of the orifice. Then the nondigestible material is spat back out.

This means they need as many mouths as possible to maximise the amount of food that can be processed at once. Mouths on the sides of the animal is a good location for the arms to put stuff in the mouths,